# Page not redirecting after stripe checkout

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, stripe-payments, checkout

I'm trying to add a stripe checkout button to my Leadpages landing page and after somebody completes a successful payment they're supposed to be redirected...but that redirect is not happening and I have no idea why.

Here's my page: http://snapstories.leadpages.co/test/... it's using test keys right now so you can test the checkout with Stripe's demo Visa number: 4242424242424242 and any expiry / security code...you'll see that you don't get redirected anywhere.

The demo-stripe.php script is supposed to send a 'success' response to my front-end code which triggers the redirect but that 'success' response is not being sent.

Here's the demo-stripe.php code:

```
    <?php
require_once('./stripe/init.php');

$stripe = array(
  "secret_key"      => "sk_test_******",
  "publishable_key" => "pk_test_******"
);

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);
// Get the credit card details submitted by the form
$token  = $_GET['stripeToken'];
$email  = $_GET['stripeEmail'];
$callback = $_GET['callback'];

try {
    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
      "source" => $token,
   "email" => $email
      ));
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  'customer' => $customer->id,
     'amount'   => 100,
      'currency' => 'usd'
    ));


    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $response_array['status'] = 'success';
    echo $callback.'('.json_encode($response_array).')';
    return 1;

} 

catch ( \Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
    // Since it's a decline, \Stripe\Error\Card will be caught
}
?>
```

Here's the front-end code:

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>

<script>
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: 'pk_test_*****',
  image: 'imagefile.png',
  locale: 'auto',
  token: function(token) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      url: "https://snapstories.co/demo-stripe.php",
      data: { stripeToken: token.id, stripeEmail: token.email},
      success: function(data) {
          window.location.href = "http//www.google.com";
    },

   });
  }
});

document.getElementsByClassName('w-f73e4cf1-859d-e3e4-97af-8efccae7644a')[0].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // Open Checkout with further options:
  handler.open({
    name: 'Testing',
    description: 'testing',
    amount: 100
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});


// Close Checkout on page navigation:
window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
  handler.close();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please put the code into your post as text, not as images.

Comment: Updated, no more images.

Comment: hi @jam , I'm just trying to make a similar configuration with leadpages and stripe ( do the checkout and set the redirect url to my main side ) I can't find any documentation from stripe/leadpages around this. are you please able to point me in the right direction ?

Comment: The page I found on Stripe doesn't seem to exist anymore (I'm sure you came across this already)... wonder if the configuration no longer works? https://stripe.com/works-with/leadpages

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your front-end code doesn't get to the success function.

Web console returns:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

It looks like you're using the jQuery command `$.ajax()`, but I can't see where you've loaded the jQuery library. Try and load it above the script that uses it and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to double check the Stripe Checkout requirements. It seems, based on the link you posted, that you're using the **HTTP** protocol. Stripe Checkout requires you use the **HTTPS** protocol. That means if you're not using an **ssl certificate** on your page using Checkout, your page isn't going to return a token nor will it execute any further.